# What kind of class/object uses information about several objects to represent a larger system?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class Tree that "has" zero or more Branches, and each Branch "has" zero or more Fruit, etc.

Let's say I want to create one object that allows you to treat all of that data as a single object, so a user of my interface wouldn't say "Tree, iterate through all of your branches. For each branch, add how many fruit there are to a total." but instead would just say "Tree, how many fruit do you have?" or "How many Apples do you have?"

What kind of object is this? What design pattern is applicable?

Comment: I don't know that you need a design pattern. A static method which hides the details of iterating would seem appropriate. From the description of your example, it sounds like *some* method will need to iterate through the branches.

Comment: Yeah, something will have to iterate, but the point is hiding that from the user and exposing a new interface. Granted my example is somewhat silly, but my point is I want to create a new interface that gives some functionality independent of the implementation of the object or set of objects being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is precisely the [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) Pattern:

> Compose objects into tree structures to represent part-whole
>   hierarchies.  Composite lets clients treat individual objects and
>   compositions of objects uniformly.

As an aside, the use of the Composite pattern does ineed allow you to easily use a Visitor to act upon the nodes of your tree.

Comment: Upon further reflection, my answer addresses the question title of "What kind of class/object uses information about several objects to represent a larger system" but the question *content* seems more about the iterator abstraction.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the Visitor Pattern to me - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern.

In the wikipedia article they give an example of a Car which is composed of Car elements.  There is a base class CarElementVisitor.  The elements and the base visitor class collaborate to allow iteration though the tree.

In your case you might have a base class TreeElementVisitor which knows how to navigate through the tree, fruit etc.

```
"Tree, how many fruit do you have?"
```

To solve this problem you create a subclass of TreeElementVisitor called FruitCountingVisitor which keeps a running count as a member variable.  All the `visitFruit` methods increment the counter.  Other methods such as `visitTree`, `visitBranch` etc. do nothing.

```
Tree tree = // create a tree
FruitCountingVisitor visitor = // create the visitor
tree.accept(visitor);
System.out.println(visitor.getCount());
```

You could then create an AppleCountingVisitor - or perhaps generalize the FruitCountingVisitor to filter on specific fruit based on a constructor argument.

Answer (score 1):

You might be curious about non Java-specific solutions too, in which case I think you could use a *fold*. Wikipedia gives a description of a very generalized approach to iterating over tree-like structures and generating some type of result from that iteration:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism#Example

Also see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)